# Vectorize nested for loop, R

Tags: r, vector, vectorization, nested-loops

Actually, I want to create a vector "compare" form another vector "data".
I want to compare each element in "data" with himself and all the element that follows in the vector. If there is a tie I append 1 to "compare" if not I append 0.
For example:

```
data=c(3,6,7,3)
# I compare 3 to 3, 6, 7 and 3
# Then I compare 6 to 6, 7, and 3
# Then 7 to 7 an 3
# Then 3 to 3 so I get
compare=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
```

Here is what I have done:

```
for(i in 1:length(data))
{
  for(j in 0:(length(data)-i))
  {
     if (data[i]==data[i+j])
     {
        compare=append(compare,1)
     }
     else
     {
        compare=append(compare,0)
     }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to vectorize this kind of comparison between vectors elements?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `dist`:

```
data=c(3,6,7,3)
res <- as.matrix(dist(data))
res <- res < .Machine$double.eps #find elements with distance of 0
diag(res) <- 1
res[lower.tri(res, TRUE)]
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `outer` to compare `data` with itself and then extract lower triangular data so that we get output of only the data which follows the current value.

```
mat <- +(outer(data, data, `==`))
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)]
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sapply on index:

```
as.numeric(unlist(sapply(1:length(data), function(k) data[k] == data[k:length(data)])))
[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Current value of index k is compared with all values equal or after k. `unlist` allows to concatenate the result of each iteration k. Finally `as.numeric`transforms booleans to integers.